# How to increase more than 100? I need to do 4200

Tags: excel, database

I have data and I want to reshape. The formula is limited for 100. How to increase it in excel?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$100, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D89, $A$2:$A$100),0)),"")

=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$100, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D89, $A$2:$A$100),0)),"")
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `100` for `4200` in the formula ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to edit the sheer # of rows you are counting.

```
Try this:
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$100, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D89, $A$2:$A$4200),0)),"")

=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$100, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D89, $A$2:$A$4200),0)),"")
```

By changing `A100` to `A4200`, we can change the range to which this formula applies.